# PromiseKit flatMapError

Tags: ios, promise, frp

ReactiveSwift has this great function called `flatMapError` that allows you to respond with an event stream when an error occurs. A simple example might look like:

```
authenticationProducer.flatMapError { _ in self.reauthenticate() }
```

Whenever an error occurs, that error gets mapped into a producer that attempts to re-authenticate.

How would I build a similar operator using PromiseKit? The function signature would look like:

```
func flatMapError<U>(_ transform: @escaping (Error) -> Promise<U>) -> Promise<U>
```

My implementation so far:

```
func flatMapError<U>(_ transform: @escaping (Error) -> Promise<U>) -> Promise<U> {
    return Promise<U> { resolve, reject in
        self.catch { error in
            let promise = transform(error)
            let _ = promise.then { value in
                resolve(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `recover`, it behaves as you request.

https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Sources/Promise.swift#L254-L278